# C/Assembly Subprogram Segmentation fault

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault, gdb

Trying to run through GDB and keep getting a segmentation fault once the C main program enters the main function.

GDB Error:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at binom_main.c:7
7   n=10;
(gdb) s
10  0;
(gdb) s
12  +){
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005c4 in otherwise ()
(gdb)
```

I compiled the code as such:

```
as binom.s -o binom.o
gcc -S -Og binom_main.c
gcc -c binom_main.s    
gcc binom_main.o binom.o -o runtimes
```

I'm trying to learn how to use GDB more efficiently here but segfaults like these are pretty ambiguous and limiting. Why is this segfault being caused the moment the function begins? Have I linked the two files incorrectly?

Main :

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int result,m,n,i;
unsigned int binom(int,int);
int main(){

n=10;
i=0;


for (i=1; i<2;i++){

result = binom(n,i);

printf("i=%d | %d \n", i, result );

}

return 0;


}
```

Sub:

```
    .text
    .globl  binom

binom: 
    mov     $0x00, %edx     #for difference calculation
    cmp     %edi, %esi          #m=n?
    je      equalorzero         #jump to equalorzero for returning of value 1
    cmp     $0x00, %esi         #m=0?
    je      equalorzero     
    cmp     $0x01, %esi         #m=1?

    mov     %esi,%edx
    sub     %edi, %edx
    cmp     $0x01, %edx         # n-m = 1 ?
    je      oneoronedifference  

    jmp     otherwise

equalorzero:
    add     $1, %eax            #return 1

    call    printf  
    ret 

oneoronedifference:
    add     %edi, %eax          #return n
    ret

otherwise:
    sub     $1, %edi            #binom(n-1,m) 
    call    binom       
    sub     $1, %esi            #binom(n-1,m-1)
    call    binom
    ret
```

Comment: Is that all the commands you ran? I don't see where the two `.o` files have been linked. You need to do something like `gcc -o binom binom_main.o binom.o`.

Comment: On second look, sounds like a textbook case of stack overflow (haha). Note you get the fault `in otherwise ()` so it's definitely not right at entering `main`. PS: you use `printf` wrong too, that may or may not be a contributing factor.

Comment: @kaylum Yep! I forgot to include that in the OP. I edited it in though. Sorry about that.

Comment: @jester How am I using printf incorrectly? The format doesn't look incorrect to me after cross checking with the c library function page http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Comment: In the asm code, you have a `call printf` without any valid arguments set up.

Comment: No clue how that got there - It wasn't supposed to have any prints -.- Okay I'll see if that was the cause of the segfault. I hope it's the case. Ty Jester!

Comment: Still getting a Segfault - this time after the first iteration of the loop. `vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7dd4400 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x400664 "m = %d | %d \n", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffdf78)
    at vfprintf.c:270
270 vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.` 

Which doesnt make sense to me - I thought I defined both argv as being integers.

Comment: @Jester I think It might be because my subprogram isn't returning an integer but rather a register, %rax, with a value in it. How do I go about returning an int from the subprogram?

Comment: That's how you do it. Also, your loop only has a single iteration, you can't have a fault "after" it.

Comment: Furthermore your `otherwise` has two `call binom` but the result from the first one is discarded, and you never save `edi` or `esi`.

Comment: @Jester: well-spotted.  The whole thing is just riddled with bugs >.<  Which is normal for a beginner, and hopefully the OP would have been able to find and fix them after the crash-bug was resolved so they'd become visible.

Comment: 9 questions the last month on how to use gdb. Please just RTFM. Honest, it is the best investment you can make right now. Also, probably the best way to get started with writing your own asm is to code something in C, compile with -S, and look at the output. At least the compiler will show you how to setup the stack frames and give you a hint about which registers to save/restore.

Comment: @evaitl Ty, reading through it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use gdb to debug asm, look at the disassembly window as well as the source window.  (e.g. `layout asm` / `layout reg`, and `layout next` until you get the combo of windows that you want.)  See the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for some more tips and a link to docs.

You can use `stepi` (`si`) to step by instructions, not by C statements, while investigating a crash outside your asm, caused by it corrupting something before returning.

---

This looks like a bug:

```
sub     $1, %edi            #binom(n-1,m) 
call    binom
# at this point, %edi no longer holds n-1, and %esi no longer holds m.
# because binom clobbers them.  (This is normal)

# as Jester points out, you also don't save the return value (%eax) from the first call anywhere.
sub     $1, %esi            #binom(n-1,m-1)
call    binom
```

---

Another (minor?) bug is:

```
cmp     $0x01, %esi         #m=1?
# but then you never read the flags that cmp set
```

---

Another serious bug:

```
equalorzero:
    add     $1, %eax            #return 1  # wrong: nothing before this set %eax to anything.
    # mov  $1, %eax             #  You probably want this instead
    ret
```

Comment: How do you break into the asm program? I get this from the compiler `(gdb) break binom.s:12
No source file named binom.s.
`  because I only get this `(gdb) si
0x000000000040054b 12 result = binom(n,i);
` from the `si` gdb command.

Comment: @Egyptian_Coder: Why don't you compile with debug symbols like a normal person?  `gcc -g binom_main.c -Og binom.S  -o runtimes` to compile/assemble/link everything in one command.  I'd recommend `.S` for hand-written asm source, even if it doesn't need the C preprocessor.

Comment: @Egyptian_Coder: but to set a breakpoint at a numeric address, you use `b *0x000000000040054b`.  (i.e. dereference the address like a pointer).  Also, I think what you saw is just that you only single-stepped one of the instructions that's part of the setup for the call.  So it's an instruction that's part of the caller side of `binom(n,i)`.  You'd have seen this if you set up gdb to show a disassembly window like I suggested.  step more times until you've stepped into the asm function.  Or just `s` into the asm function, and *then* `si` through it and out.